# When calling a stored procedure it cannot find the database in Node and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure in nodejs and my database is made in mysql, currently I need to copy a table into a new database, when trying to test my method it throws me the message **ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected**. the method of which I call this stored procedure is as follows.

```js
  var mysql = require('mysql');
    var uuid = require('uuid');
    let config = require('../config/db.config');

let connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

let  sql = `CALL ReplyDB(?)`;
    
     app.post('/', function (req, res) {
        connection.query(sql,true, (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) {
              return console.error("Fallo la replicación" , error.message);
            }
            console.log("El id único es: ", uuid.v4());
            console.log(" Replicación completada", results[0]);
          });
          
          connection.end();
        
    });
```

the stored procedure it generates is as follows.

```js
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE `demo`.`ReplyDB`(IN done BOOLEAN)
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO testdb.backup_sales_order
  SELECT * 
  FROM demo.sales_order;
 END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I do not receive any parameters, I just need that when I position myself in the main path, the method is executed and the data is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

*db.config*

has also to have a database in it

Like:

```
var databaseOptions = {
    host     : 'localhost',
    database : 'demo',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'secretpassword',
    port     : '3306'
};
```

or call `use demo`

Like:

```
let database = 'demo';
connection.query(`USE ${database}`, (error, results, fields) => {
    ...
  });
```

every call to a mysql function must have a hook that is a database

so  spencer7593 is of course right, that

```
let  sql = 'CALL demo.ReplyDB(?)';
```

Would also do the trick, but i thought that you want to run more query on demo, so using USE or using demo in the connection string, would make it easier.

Comment: i suspect   `CALL demo.ReplyDB(?)`  would also avoid the error